# Spring boot rest endpoint returning null with fetch request

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I have already created Rest Endpoint in Java spring boot. It returns appropriate response when I request it via Postman. But when I use react [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) it does not show any response in browser if return is Json.

Spring boot controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/test")
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Autowired})
public class TestController {
    ...
}
```

Below endpoint is returning appropriate response.

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/helloWorld", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello, World1!";
  }
```

[image]

But when I try to hit below endpoint it returns null when I make `fetch` request. But it returns appropriate response when I hit it via postman.

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/testEndpoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public String returnTestResponse() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("results", "value2");
    return "{\"a\":1, \"b\":\"foo\"}";
  }
```

[image]

Also tried returning POJO object. But still no response.

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/testModel", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public SearchResultsModel testModel() {
    this.myService.getSearchResult();
  }
```

React fetch call:

```
await fetch(ALL_ARTICLES_ENDPOINT, {
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: can you show how you annotated controller class?

Comment: Updated post. Added controller annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by adding `mode: 'no-cors'` option in fetch request. This option helped me to get rid of cors error but it means that in return I won't be able to see body and headers in chrome.

To resolve the issue I removed `mode: 'no-cors'` and added `@CrossOrigin` annotation on my spring boot controller.

Answer (score 1):

Postman have couple hidden headers which are being sent with all requests.
Check `Hide auto-generated headers`

[image]

What you are missing in react call is is `Accept` header with `application/json` value

EDIT:

Just saw that you are returning string as json. You need to wrap it in POJO object and return it in returnTestResponse class

SECOND EDIT:

This will work. Try to implement your POJO

```
@GetMapping(value = "/testEndpoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public YourObject returnTestResponse() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("results", "value2");
    return new YourObject(map);
  }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I already tried adding `Accept` application/json to my request but output is same. I will update the post

Comment: and you can't see any errors in server logs? What's response status code?

Comment: It returns `200 OK` but no response

Comment: Just added EDIT section, check it out

Comment: you are still returning String in that method. Return your POJO class or change procudes to application/text

Comment: Just implemented the way you suggested but it still returns null. Copy pasted the URL in chrome directly and it shows the response. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Stuck with this issue for more than 8 hours :faceplam:

Comment: I'm not familiar with react, but maybe try with await fetch(ALL_ARTICLES_ENDPOINT
  ).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });